# HTML-parsing regular expression

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I want to parse an [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) document and get all users' nicknames.

They are in this format:

```
<a href="/nickname_u_2412477356587950963">Nickname</a>
```

How can I do it using a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in PHP? I can't use DOMElement or simple HTML parsing.

Comment: Oblig: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why can't you use an HTML parser?

Comment: You don't need a regex, you can do it with [DomDocument::loadHTML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working solution without using a regular expression:

DomDocument::loadHTML() is forgetting enough to work on malformed [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML).

```
<?php
    $doc = new DomDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML('<a href="/nickname_u_2412477356587950963">Nickname</a>');

    $xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
    $nodes = $xpath->query('//a[starts-with(@href, "/nickname")]');

    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $username = $node->textContent;
        $href = $node->getAttribute('href');
        printf("%s => %s\n", $username, $href);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but you guys didnt understand what I meant, "nickname" is a variable and so is this random set of numbers

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match_all(
    '{                  # match when
        nickname_u_     # there is nickname_u
        [\d+]*          # followed by any number of digits
        ">              # followed by quote and closing bracket
        (.*)?           # capture anything that follows
        </a>            # until the first </a> sequence
    }xm',
    '<a href="/nickname_u_2412477356587950963">Nickname</a>',
    $matches
);
print_r($matches);
```

Usual disclaimers for using Regex on HTML over an [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) apply. Above can probably be improved to more reliable matching. [It will work for the example you gave though.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NkVtAR)